# Autosizing pictures with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need to place 3 picture boxes, which are all in a own panel, side by side.

Conditions:

- all pictures should stay side by side in same distance to each other
- the pictures should grow and shrink during resizing the Form
- the Panels under the pB's should always act like a border to the pictures
- it should be used as much as possible space

How could I do this in Visual Studio 2010 C#, Windows Forms?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 columns that you dock/anchor into place?

Comment: Subscribe to the OnResize event and edit the width and possition of each panel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a `TableLayoutPanel` with 3 columns, and place the pictureboxes within the given cells.

Anchor this panel to the parent form, so that when you resize the form, the panel will follow. Since you have panels underneath (as per picture sample) you could anchor to `Left`, `Right` and `Top`. This will anchor the panel to top, left, and will resize all the way to the right for as long as the form goes. Add `Bottom` if you need to.

The pictureboxes would have the `Dock` set to `DockStyle.Fill`.

You could nest more panels within panels, but do it in a sane way :-)

Comment: I cant see my borders after setting the pictures to dock.fill :-/ The rest works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think ,following these instructions will fulfill your requirements

1)right click on other panels and select bring to front

2)anchor the other panels to bottom

3)anchor all other panels panels and picture boxes to top,bottom ,left,right using properties
You can manage the interfaces selection ,un-selecting anchors